# Where I can get oracle from builder 6?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I need Oracle form builder 6.0.(report also)

would you help me where I can find it?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Forms 6.0 is rather ancient.  Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't make software that old publicly available.

If you are actually licensed for Forms 6.0 and your support contract is current, you could try logging a Service Request with [Oracle Support](http://metalink.oracle.com).  A support representative may be able to find an archived copy of the software they could send you.

Answer (score 0):

Where else but from the [Oracle Technet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html) (did you actually look) but this is a development only license. For commercial use, you need to buy it from Oracle

Comment: Technet has Forms and Reports, but that is for recent/ current versions.  Forms 6.0 is older than my career so Oracle doesn't bother making it available.

Comment: @Justin - "Forms 6.0 is older than my career ".  Forms 6.o was the third version of the product I used, so how old does that make me?

Comment: @APC - That doesn't make you old.  That makes you wise.  Wise enough that I'm pretty sure you're not trying to use Forms 6.0 today.

Comment: the problem is previous project written in 6i and now I need to install it in my computer :((